# How to identify Azure Service Bus Requests

Tags: azureservicebus

I'm trying to identify what exactly is hitting my Azure Service Bus. The overview page in the Azure portal shows many requests, but I'm deliberately keeping off it and so I need to know what's going on.

[image: Last 6 hours' of service bus operation - 0 message, many requests.]

I've enabled diagnostics logging into a storage account, but there's very little information there, only 10-12 entries for 12 hours' running. I've also enabled Log Analytics, but there's no information there to be found. So I'm a bit of a loss as to what's going on behind the scenes. How can I properly identify what these requests are all about?

Comment: Do you have a service that dequeue the messages using `OnMessage` ? When you use OnMessage, your service do a pull frequently to check if there are new messages

Comment: @Thomas I do not. The Service Bus has no queues. As for topics there is only one topic, with two subscriptions. As no messages are coming in, those subscriptions will never be triggered.

Comment: No but what I mean do you have a listener for each of your subscription ?

Comment: @Thomas This I do, for one of them there's an Azure function that reacts when that subscription's filter criteria is met.

Comment: This is the reason why you see requests in your servicebus namespace. Azure function pull messages. So every X seconds the function will hit your servicebus subscription to check if there are new messages.

Comment: @Thomas Dang. That's disappointing (to me) - I was hoping the Azure Function would somehow magically, without polling, be notified of new services bus subscription-hits. Such as is the case with auto-notifications when an item goes into a storage queue, for example. Thanks for clearing it up. Please leave a answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Yeah sometime there is no magic :-)